# I am trying to clone project from bitbucket and running in VS Code while doing npm install showing a lot of errors, warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm, npm-install

I have project on bitbucket and trying to clone it, the project is very older 3 year old so might be some packages do get old. But while I am doing `npm install` so it is showing a lot of warning and errors. Also the project at beginning made with Yarn not NPM.

Some warning and error looks like:

```
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fe
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7[1] || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used incommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
```

Comment: What's your _question_? Yes, a 3+ year old project might have some out-of-date dependencies that have since been discovered to be vulnerable.

Comment: You already answered your question with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `package-lock.json` and then execute `npm install` (or `yarn install` if you prefer).

Have in mind that being this an old project. Some of the packages passed for major changes and may possibly not run as expected anymore. Major changes are not necessarily backward compatible, so you may have to change a lot of code in order to make your code work. Be ready to have a lot of fun coding!

**EDIT:** Considering the `package.json` you posted in a comment, my suggestion is creating a new app using `npx create-react-app` and then moving your ReactJS code to it. This way you would have a completely updated app and would have only to review your code.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I tried to remove package-lock.json and try executing npm install but when running npm start. it shows 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Could you post you package.json file, please?

Comment: I have attached here pls check 

https://pastebin.com/40CwHiBY

Comment: I see... Your packages are really old. I am editing my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: thanks . for editing it . But moving app won't create problem as I need the same files and its already an important project

Comment: Move `index.js`, `App.js` and the `src` folder. It will be the same app, but with the setup of a newer one in terms of packages. IMPORTANT: KEEP A BACKUP OF EVERYTHING BEFORE DOING THIS.

Comment: Of course, you will have to make lots of changes. As I told you in my answer, many packages had major changes and there will be lots of adjustments to make.

Comment: sir is their any direct way where i can communicate with you and ask my queries please it will be very appreciated

Comment: edvaldoajunior@gmail.com